# Logitech G300 : Mouse buttons not working

Tags: 16.04, drivers

I've finally managed to install Ubuntu in dual boot on my PC. Only problem is that I can't use my mouse, which is a Logitech G300.

Basically, the only things that work are the pointer and the scroll up/down. All clicks from all button just do nothing.

Every issue about this mouse seems to be about erratic behaviours of the buttons, or remapping them but I don't have any behaviour at all.

I've tried the methods in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/63283/logitech-g300-not-working-on-ubuntu) but nothing works.
I've also tried to use the command `xinput test <id>` to see what is going wrong and the results are quite surprising.

Basically, the mouse is listed twice in the xinput list : Once as a mouse, once as a keyboard.
When I test the mouse side, clicking the buttons do nothing, as I would expect (Moving and scrolling do work though). Testing the keyboard side however, shows that the buttons events are registered, but fired as motion events I guess.

Since I'm back on Windows to write this question, I don't have the exact results but a left click would result in something like this :

```
motion[a]=1
motion[a]=0
```

I also checked the button mapping for both the mouse and keyboard device, and the mouse has a 1 to 24 mapping, whereas the keyboard has nothing.

Is there anything I can do ? I'm honestly all out of ideas and I don't really want to buy another mouse when this one works fine ...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have a Mouse with 3 buttons and I've configured them based on this thread.

You will have to install xev to determine the mouse buttons and clicks.

Sudo apt-get install xev

run it in a terminal

xev

it should prompt you a box figure point your mouse there and click your mouse from left click to right click as well as the buttons do this one at a time and take note of the button number(e.g left click = button = 1 )

then you can proceed to mapping by editing your xorg.conf(But make sure to have a backup first.

cp /etc/X11/xorg.conf /etc/X11/xorg.conf.old

vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf

Add this to the end of the line

Section "InputDevice"

```
Identifier  "Configured Mouse"

Driver      "mouse"

Option      "CorePointer"

Option      "Protocol"  "ExplorerPS/2"

Option      "ZAxisMapping"  "8 9"

Option      "Device"    "/dev/input/mice"
```

EndSection

Logout then login back again.

This is only an example of what I had where 8 and 9 are my buttons for forward and back mappings.

for more information I suggest you visit this link.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MouseCustomizations

Hope this helps.